# Java: Make server stop listening after certain amount of time

Tags: java, loops, sockets, while-loop, timeout

Im currently coding a client-server application. The client is configured to try to connect to the server every 20 seconds. If the server is available, it accepts the request. The server can accept several requests and is run in a while loop. However, the loop goes infinitely but I want the server to stop listening/accepting requests after 20 seconds. Unfortunatly I don't know how to do this.

I already tried:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
while(false||(System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime)<10000)
```

But that doesnt work. If there is a connection it only stops listening after the request arrived again after the time ran out and if there is no connection it won't stop at all.

```
            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                   while(true) {
                       try {
                           ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(intport); 
                           Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); 


                              OutputStream socketoutstr = clientSocket.getOutputStream(); 
                              OutputStreamWriter osr = new OutputStreamWriter( socketoutstr ); 
                              BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( osr ); 

                              InputStream socketinstr = clientSocket.getInputStream(); 
                              InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader( socketinstr ); 
                              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( isr ); 

                              String anfrage; 
                              String antwort; 

                              anfrage = br.readLine(); 
                              antwort = anfrage; 
                              bw.write(antwort); 
                              bw.newLine(); 
                              bw.flush(); 
                              System.out.println(antwort);
                              logs.append(antwort);
                              logs.append(newline);

                              bw.close(); 
                              br.close(); 
                              clientSocket.close(); 
                              serverSocket.close(); 


                       } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }finally{}                     

                   }


                }
            });


            logs.append("Is someone out there?");
            logs.append(newline);   
            t.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: The big question is WHY?  You need to explain to us why you want to do that, and why your code is organized synchronously instead of passing each incoming request to its own thread for processing.  There is almost never a legitimate need to write the processing loop the way you've done it.  This structure makes the server stall, with no chance of doing anything, while waiting for a request to arrive.

Comment: The only purpose of this server is to create a list of all the clients trying to connect to it and printing that onto a JTextarea.

Comment: Still, you need to read up on the standard way of writing a network server.  The main loop accepts the connections and passes them off to worker threads to handle each connection, allowing you to have multiple simultaneous connections active (i.e. a standard server).  To stop after a fixed time, launch a thread that pauses and then calls `ServerSocket#close()`.